# Deleting a file, deletes a copy of the file JS

Tags: javascript, file, copy, blob, deep-copy

I have a file input and I am trying to save the selected file into an object of all the selected files so in the future I can submit them.
The problem is that whenever a new file is chosen in the file input, the other files are deleted in the object.
I tried copying the file, or doing deep copy but it doesn't work,
or something like this:

```
var filesObj = {}
var i = 0;
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput')
fileInput.addEventListener("change", function(ev){
    let file = fileInput.files[0];
    let blob = new Blob([file], {type: file.type});
    let fileCopy = new File([file], file.name, { type: file.type, lastModified: file.lastModified });
    filesObj[i] = fileCopy;
    i++
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include some more context; it's hard to help you judging from the amount of content you posted.

Comment: `let file = fileInputs.files[0]` is always referring to the same file. Did you mean `let file = fileInputs.files[i]`?

Comment: No, because when you chose a different file, the file is not added into the `fileInputs.files` array, it is placed in the `fileInputs.files[0]` and takes over the other file which was chosen, therefore it is a different file.